# How can you see the bounce rate and number of page views for a URL in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am working with the API, but using the Explore reports uncovers the same problem. I cannot see how many page views a given path has while also seeing the bounce rate. It just becomes 100 %.

If I only add page path and date as dimensions and filter by path, I get what I expect:

[image: Bounce rate]

GA4 has moved page views into events as far as I understand it. So I add EventName to the report and filter by "page_view". Now I get this:

[image: Bounce rate becomes 100%]

I see the bounce rate seems to be calculated from the session_start event:

[image: Session start event]

It's not clear to me how I can get the bounce rate and page view data in the same report like this. It was easy on UA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is to not be an idiot. Don't use the event "page_views", but use the built-in metric "Views". I am not sure how I missed that.