# Google Analytics API: Bounce Rate value not being returned correctly and Average Engagement Time not being in the API

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to create a project where I use the Google Analytics API to pull the Bounce Rate, Views and Average Engagement Time from the "**Page path and screen class**" Dimension from the API for a property I have.
While the Views are being pulled correctly, I seem to be facing an issue with the other two.

In the case of Bounce Rates, the API returns that the Bounce Rate of each page is **1**, no matter what the front end has to say about that. Also, the page names displayed by the API in regards to Bounce Rates are incorrect, that is, they are displayed in URL encoding when I don't have pages with that format.

Lastly, I can't seem to locate the **Average Engagement Time** in the API documentation or anywhere online at all. It isn't [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#metrics), which is the official documentation of this API neither somewhere else.

For reference, I use the below piece of code for the Bounce Rates:

```
$bounce_rate = $client->runReport(['property' => 'properties/' . $id, 'dateRanges' => [new DateRange(['start_date' => $first_day, 'end_date' => $last_day])], 'dimensions' => [new Dimension(['name' => 'unifiedPagePathScreen'])], 'metrics' => [new Metric(["name" => "bounceRate"])]]);

foreach ($bounce_rate->getRows() as $g_row) {
    $value = $g_row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue();
    $email_body .= $g_row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue() . ' ';
    $email_body .= $value . "\n";
```

Comment: does this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76788324/how-can-you-see-the-bounce-rate-and-number-of-page-views-for-a-url-in-google-ana] help you?